# Practically expected transfer rates for SDHC class 6

Tags: memory, flash, speed

I went and bought an expensive [SanDisk Extreme III SDHC 8GB](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B001940S1C) class 6 chip.

However, when I dump data from the card to the machine via a USB 2.0 cable, it's only getting 5.0 MB/second **maximum** according to Windows 7's disk explorer. It still can take up to 20 minutes to dump the card when it's near full.

This is **so far** below the rated 20 MB/s transfer speed. I can't believe it.

Is this normal or might I have a defective chip?

Answer (score 1):

This class of SD card should support a [minimum transfer speed of about 6MB/s](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_Digital#Speeds), which would agree with your test of 8GB read in 20mins (6.67MB/s mean). However, I believe the manufacturer is free to quote any maximum transfer speed they can come up with (probably the maximum sequential read speed under ideal, de-fragmented conditions).

I suspect this may be the limit of the card, but have you tried formatting the card with a different file system?

So, based on the link you provided, you could possibly argue with Amazon/the seller that the product description was misleading - it did not specify that 20MB/s was the **maximum** sequential read/write speed.

Answer (score 1):

Slightly off-topic but I think it is still relevant: I have seen different card readers make a 10x difference in speed. If you have any other readers around, that may be worth testing.

Also, the Windows Explorer reported speed works funny - there is a ton of buffering and other I/O magic that happens that really can hide performance.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a [review](http://www.barefeats.com/flash06.html) comparing SD and CF memory cards, which shows SD cards like yours getting 14.5 MB/sec or so. Admittedly, these benchmarks are on a Mac. Perhaps your SD card reader or CPU is the bottleneck?